# $(ab^{n+1})^{1/n}$ where $a,b \in \mathbb{C}$

Tags: complex-numbers, roots-of-unity

Let $a,b \in \mathbb{C}$ and $n \in \mathbb{N}$. We can present $a$ and $b$ in polar form as

\begin{equation}
a = r_a \mathrm{e}^{i \theta_a} \quad \textrm{and} \quad b = r_b \mathrm{e}^{i \theta_b},
\end{equation}

where $r_a,r_b \in \mathbb{R}_+$ are radii, $\theta_a,\theta_b \in [0,2\pi]$ are angles and $i$ is the imaginary unit.

Say we have

\begin{equation}
a b^{n+1} = r_a \mathrm{e}^{i \theta_a} r_b^{n+1} \mathrm{e}^{i(n + 1)\theta_b}
\end{equation}

and we would like to determine $(a b^{n+1})^{1/n}$. Is it correct to say

\begin{equation}
(a b^{n+1})^{1/n} = x_i r_b (r_a r_b)^{1/n} \mathrm{e}^{i \theta_a/n} \mathrm{e}^{i(n + 1)\theta_b/n} = x_i b a^{1/n} b^{1/n} = x_i a^{1/n} b^{1 + 1/n}, \quad i = 1,2,\ldots,n,
\end{equation}

where $x_i$ is the $i$th root of unity $x^n = 1$ and $(r_a r_b)^{1/n}$, $a^{1/n}$ and $b^{1/n}$ are *principal roots*, i.e. the root having smallest positive angle?

Comment: You don't need all the small steps in between, your solution is the same as your initial term... but yes, it is correct

Comment: @Inuyaki That was just to made the steps clear for myself and for someone to point out the possible error. To be clear, you agree that $(ab^{n+1})^{1/n} = x_i a^{1/n} b^{1 + 1/n}, ~ i = 1,2,\ldots,n$?